# How get nested entity in Typeorm?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

How to correctly get nested entity? In example, i make this query:

```
const houseId = 1;
const userId = 1;

const house = await this.houseRepository.findOne({
  id: houseId,
}, {
  where: {
    project: {
      user: {
        id: userId,
      }
    }
  },
  relations: ['project', 'project.user']
});
```

As a result, `house` variable contain `project` entity, but `project` do not contain `user`. How to include `user` into `project`?
As i understand from the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations), the `user` property in `project` entity was declared as lazy and if i want to get it, i should resolve it:

```
const user = await house.project.user;
console.log(user);
-> undefined
```

But resolving `user` give undefined in console, especially since it undefined before resolve.

House entity class:

```
@Entity('house')
export class HouseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => ProjectEntity, { eager: true })
  project: ProjectEntity;
}
```

Project entity class:

```
@Entity('project')
export class ProjectEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.projects)
  user: UserEntity;
}
```

User entity class:

```
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  first_name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => ProjectEntity, project => project.user)
  projects: ProjectEntity[];
}
```

Comment: You have declared the `project` relation as eager not lazy. To load it lazy, it has to return a promise. So, here you are awaiting a plain value not a promise.